# Insert image in latex

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)

Hi! I'm trying to insert an image in latex with some text around:

```
Here is our image: 
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{idefA0.jpg}
    \caption{IDEF0} 
    \end{figure} 
Here is some text!
```

I'd like to insert image and 'Here is some image' on the same page, but when i'm trying to compile pdf I get: `Warning! !h changed to !ht` and places an image on the next page, and `here is some text` goes right after `Here is some image`

Comment: The `float` package with the `[H]` placement option should help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text/8633#8633

Comment: no, it doesn't help, i've already tryied all flags=\

Comment: In that case, can you please post a full minimal example, including the preamble (so starting from `\documentclass`) that shows the described behaviour?

Comment: @jake `\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` and than `\chapter{Name}` and code from my 1st post. I think, the main problem is - I have about 4-6 lines of free space at this place=\

Comment: You can edit your original question to include the preamble. Note that, in order to use the `[H]` option to place the image, you need to add the line `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble.

Comment: @jake tnx a lot. It helped!

Comment: @Jake: Good advice! Please add it as answer, so that @Fluffy could accept it later.

Comment: @Stefan: I assume the question will be closed as a duplicate (of the question I linked to in my first comment), so there's probably no need to add an answer here that can be accepted?

Comment: @Jake,Stefan: I'm actually in favor for closing it as duplicate of [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/2975). It is basically the same. Ok, here the main point is the placement of some text relative to the float and the other question is about placing the float at a certain position, which isn't 100% the same. Anyway, the answer(s) there answer this question as well. (I'm just added an answer by myself to remind people that `figure` can also include text.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can place text (and any other material in general) into the `figure` environment together with the actual image.

So you could write:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
Here is our image: 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{idefA0.jpg}
\caption{IDEF0} 
\end{figure}
```

You have to check the spacing between the text and image by yourself, e.g. by adding a `\par\medskip` between them.

If you want to place your image in a certain position in your text you shouldn't use a floating environment (or you can use the `[H]` option as Jake mentioned).

You can write (using the `caption` package):

```
Here is our image: 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{idefA0.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{IDEF0} 
\end{center}
```