# Insert image in LaTeX

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm trying to insert an image in LaTeX with some text around:

```
Here is our image:
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{idefA0.jpg}
    \caption{IDEF0}
\end{figure}
Here is some text!
```

I'd like to insert image and 'Here is some image' on the same page, but when i'm trying to compile pdf I get:
`Warning! !h changed to !ht` and places an image on the next page, and `here is some text` goes right after `Here is some image`

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi. There is specialized place for TeX questions - http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert image in latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14170/insert-image-in-latex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)

Comment: The answer by [Matthias Vallentin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/insert-image-in-latex/14916#14916) nicely explains how to solve the problem using the `figure` environment. But you could also include an image by using `\includegraphics` in a `center` environment if you don't need or want the power of the figure environment. That would give you absolute control about the placement but you would have to give up the `\caption` as well.

Answer (score 17):

LaTeX creates a *float* if you put `includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment. Floats are containers for objects that cannot be broken across page boundaries. By using `figure`, you're essentially telling the LaTeX compiler "please put the picture where you think it fits best."

To force a picture appearing at the exact location where it is in the source code, you can do either of the following:

1. Use the `H` specifier for the figure environment. This requires `\usepackage{float}`.
2. Don't wrap `\includegraphics` into a figure environment if you just want the plain image, without caption and other extras.

Example for the first option:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{idefA0.jpg}
\caption{IDEF0}
\end{figure}
```

You find more about floats here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions.

This exact problem is already covered in more depth at: [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text).