# Inserting Images in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, positioning

I just installed MikTeX on my computer, and I'd like to know how to insert centered images within the body of a solution set I'm composing for an honors linear algebra class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14170/insert-image-in-latex) for instance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Or do you have any background about inserting pictures into your document? You might be interested to look at [`lshort`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort)

Comment: I have never inserted an image within the body of any document I've composed. I've also never looked into it. I thought this was the best place to go to ask, rather than scouring the Net.

Comment: Use `\includegraphics` to insert pre-generated images.  Otherwise I would recommend using `\tikz`, or `\pgfplots` for drawing the actual images.

Comment: @Trancot Try the [lshort](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) that I mentioned. It contains most of the basic commands that you need in order to start with LaTeX. Then if you run into a problem with your code, you can come back here to ask. Usually, we require you to give your input by asking with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Meanwhile, start with the suggestions given here in comments.

Comment: I hope, you don’t feel offended, but perhaps these are also good tips for you: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english).

Comment: @Trancot This site is a `LaTeX` gold mine for newbies.  For quick reply to your question see [wikilatex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) and always use [big-list tag](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) to filter the good latex resources questions. [Good online `LaTeX`resources](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1621/15717)

Comment: @Speravir No offense taken.